# Call stored procedure for each Row with/without using a cursor

Tags: sql, plsql

I want to a run a stored procedure for almost 1000 records (`P_SHIPMENT_GID`) in one go and below is the pseudo code.

```
DECLARE
    P_SHIPMENT_GID VARCHAR2(200);
    BEGIN
    P_SHIPMENT_GID := NULL;
    ULE_PKG_UNPLANNED_ICT_CALC.UNPLANNED_ICT_CALC(
    P_SHIPMENT_GID => P_SHIPMENT_GID
    );
    END;
```

How can I achieve this with or without using cursors?

Answer (score 0):

It is not all that clear what you want to do (where are the 1000 records from?) but here is a "pattern" I am pretty sure you can use :

```
BEGIN
   FOR i IN (SELECT table_name, status FROM user_tables) LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('name : ' || i.table_name || 
                           ' status : ' || i.status);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

This creates a loop on an *implicit cursor* and allows you to use the returned rows/column in a readable way.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply!! 1000 records exists in a table called shipment

Comment: Actually in my code in place of NULL I can pass a value of one shipment like(1246876) and I can run my procedure ,my procedure will do all the calculation for that one Shipment but point is I want to run my procedure only once and it should take all the 1000 shipments values in one go so in that case i would not have to pass single shipment ID 1000 times

Comment: Can you modify the called procedure? If you want to pass a "list" of shipments you will need to either change its type for a structure instead of a `VARCHAR2` or pass all the shipment values in some kind of comma separated list within a varchar.

Comment: If I got you right you are asking me to pass shipment vales as comma separated if yes then I tried the same by passing the values with comma separated and it has thrown me the error so I closed that point:( and it is very important for me as I need to execute this proc for 1000 records.

Comment: Hello guys can anyone please help me on this!!

Answer (score 0):

You can write this `anonymous` block for your requirement. Although its not clear from where you are storing your `SHIPMENT_GID` values which you wanted to pass to your procedure/pkg.

```
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN (               --Assuming your shipmentid are stored in a table
               SELECT SHIPMENT_GID
                 FROM Your_TABLE)
   LOOP
      ULE_PKG_UNPLANNED_ICT_CALC.UNPLANNED_ICT_CALC (
         P_SHIPMENT_GID   => rec.SHIPMENT_GID);
   END LOOP;
END;
```